# Send records to custom created Prestashop table within server database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, prestashop

I was wondering if there was a way to alter Prestashop .tpl files in order to insert a form which will take user input/details based on their sale within the "Shipping" tab, and send their information to a custom created table within the Prestashop database without having to create a module

Cheers

Comment: Yes, there is a way. But the solution is too complex to post this here within a few lines. Perhaps if you show us what you have already done we can help you with one or two specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

Within the "order-carrier.tpl" file, I've tried to insert my own block of php to write to a custom made databse within the Prestashop servers. It looks like this:

```
{literal}
function acceptCGV()
{
    if ($('#cgv').length && !$('input#cgv:checked').length)
    {
        alert(msg);
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
<!-- Inserting function to write to database
        {php}
        $recipient_details = array(
        'rep_id' => (int)0001,
        );
        Db::getInstance()->insert("ps_rep", $recipient_details);
        {/php} -->
}
{/literal}
//]]>
</script>
```

So when the user clicks next to pay, I want it to send data